# MongoDB Error: couldn't connect to server

Tags: mongodb

I have a problem for a month and I did not find a solution.Both my laptop and PC have these problems(I started mongod before):

> Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017
>   src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:91 exception: connect failed
>
> Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017
>   src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:93 exception: connect failed
>
> Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017
>   src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L112 exception: connect failed

I have started the mongod process without any parameter.And also I have a reply message by pinging 127.0.0.1

By the way I use windows os and It does not have any permission issue.
In addition I started the data directory from scratch but did not work.
(There is no error in mongod's log file)

Any help ?

Comment: Can you telnet to 127.0.0.1 27017? This would confirm whether the port is open and reachable as expected. Also can you provide the command line arguments used for the mongo shell?

Comment: telnet sais Connecting To 127.0.0.1...Could not open connection to the host, on port 27017:Connect failed.I have used several form of parameter like mongod, mongod --smallfiles --dbpath c:\db and so on.I  addition, I authunticated the 27017 and mongod process in firewall setting.But no hope.

Comment: When you start `mongod` does it wait for connections or is it immediately closing again?

Comment: No it waits for connection :  waiting for connections on port 27017

Comment: Are you attempting to connect from the same machine that your mongod process is running on?

Comment: @James Wahlin Yes it's the local machine

Comment: Try disabling your firewall completely and see if you can connect.

Comment: I have tried it but did not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops! My problem is solved.The problem was a software called "Proxifier" that blocked my localhost.I closed it and It worked properly.

Answer (score 8):

I received this error because I accidentally ran "mongo.exe" instead of "mongod.exe".  So, of course, Mongo complained that it had no database to connect to.  ;)

Comment: true faced the same issue because of mongo.exe syntax error instead of mongod

Comment: i have the same problem. even when i run mongod. this is the error :
c:\Program Files\MongoDB>mongod
2015-04-18T11:32:18.966-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory c:\data\db\ not found., terminating
2015-04-18T11:32:18.968-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100

Answer (score -1):

open your task manager..
click on services..
find mongodb and right click on it...
click on start...
bhoom your problem is resolved..
open cmd and check it