# Not able to connect to mongodb server also not getting any error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The problem is exactly what the title says, I am not able to connect to mongo db server. I don't know where the problem is. Whether its with starting the server of something else. According to the code that I have written I should get the output 'Connected Successfully'. but I am not getting any output

```
const mongodb=require('mongodb')
const MongoClient=mongodb.MongoClient
const connectionURL='mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'

const databaseName='task-manager'

MongoClient.connect(connectionURL,{useNewUrlParser:true},(error,client)=>{
    if(error){
        return console.log('Unable to connect to database')
    }
    console.log('Connected Successfully')
})
```

I have attached the related screenshots.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVDHd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL5sK.png)

Please help and thank you in advance

I tried searching for things in the documentation but could not find anything. I am expecting `console.log` statement to work in the nodejs code that I have written.

Answer (score 0):

I can see from the logs that the server is listening at 127.0.0.1:27017. However, are you sure that it is reachable?
Some other software might be blocking the access, as described in a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793753/mongodb-error-couldnt-connect-to-server).

You can confirm by running `curl http://127.0.0.1:27017` from a console terminal, if you are on Linux or Mac, or from a PowerShell window on Windows. Some other software might be blocking the access, as described in a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793753/mongodb-error-couldnt-connect-to-server).

If you get a message like below, your server is fine...

```
user@server ~]$ curl http://127.0.0.1:27017
It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.
user@server ~]$
```

The second step would be to ensure that you have the right/updated driver. I see from your screenshot that your server runs MongoDB 6.0.2, which is pretty recent.

You need at least driver v4.8 as per the [MongoDB/node driver compatibility list](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/compatibility).

Then, I would suggest to try running first a piece of code that it is confirmed working well, alongside the supported driver version.

e.g. You can try theses examples, directly from the MongoDB code-samples: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html